# FILESTREAM database options cannot be set on system databases such as 'model'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Summary of Question**

My question is for SQL Server 2017 is there a way you can re-attach the model database (without rebuilding master or restoring master) if it has been dropped given that both of the following fail

```
-- both of these do not work
sp_attach_db 'model','G:\model\model.mdf','G:\model\modellog.ldf'

CREATE DATABASE model
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

**Setup for my question**

I followed an answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39494/57571 for moving the model database which is not correct for SQL Server 2017 (I now know that the correct procedure to follow is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017).

As part of it's instructions it had the following:

```
sp_detach_db 'model'
sp_attach_db 'model','G:\model\model.mdf','G:\model\modellog.ldf'
```

Problem was that every time I tried that it would stop the running sql server (since it was trying to access the now dropped model database)

I tried using

```
CREATE DATABASE model
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

But would only get this error message

```
Msg 33401, Level 16, State 1, Server SQL01.TEST, Line 1
FILESTREAM database options cannot be set on system databases such as 'model'.
```

I ended up having to backup the databases and rebuild the master database using the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017

So rebuilt the master database with:

`Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SAPWD=StrongPa$$word`

Then manually restored all the users and databases which existed beforehand.